# What commands are executed when I press "Publish" button in Visual Studio on a web project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've developed a mini-deployment system, in which in one step I have to tell MSBuild (or anything else, I don't know) to build the web project and publish it to a file-system folder.

This is the command line I'm using:

```
MsBuild D:\Web.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Stage.pubxml
```

However, its behavior is different from when I click the `Publish` button on projects' context menu from withing Visual Studio.

How can I find out what commands are executed behind the scenes when I press Publish button in Visual Studio?

Maybe I'm searching for something like Wireshark (for network) or SQL Server Profiler (for SQL Server), for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) can show all processes activity.